# NativeScript Vue - VueX not working: TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Tags: sqlite, nativescript, state, vuex, nativescript-vue

I am trying to run the sample program 'Data Management with SQLite and Vuex in a NativeScript-Vue App'
https://nativescript.org/blog/data-management-with-sqlite-and-vuex-in-a-nativescript-vue-app/

I am getting the below error, please help in fixing this issue.

```
An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.nativescript.preview/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}: 
com.tns.NativeScriptException: Calling js method onCreate failed
TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

StackTrace:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{org.nativescript.preview/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}: com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
Calling js method onCreate failed
TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3762)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3938)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at 
 android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2277)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8425)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:596)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
Caused by: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Calling js method onCreate failed
TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
    at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1286)
    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:1173)
    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1160)
    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1138)
    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1134)
    at com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.onCreate(NativeScriptActivity.java:20)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8183)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8167)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3735)
    ... 11 more


 store.js is inside src folder.

   store.js : 
   import Vue from 'vue';
   import Vuex from 'vuex';

   Vue.use(Vuex);

    export default new Vuex.Store({
      state: {

        },
            mutations: {

          },
         actions: {
          }
         });
```

I have created a folder store inside src folder and created index.js file inside store folder. code is :

```
 import Vue from 'nativescript-vue';
 import Vuex from 'vuex';

    const Sqlite = require( "nativescript-sqlite" );
       Vue.use(Vuex);

          const store = new Vuex.Store({
           state: {
            database: null,
          data: []
        },
         mutations: {
              init(state, data) {
                 state.database = data.database;
            },
                load(state, data) {
               state.data = [];
               for(var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
                   state.data.push({
                    firstname: data.data[i][0],
                         lastname: data.data[i][1]
                    });
               }
               },
               save(state, data) {
                  state.data.push({
                    firstname: data.data.firstname,
                     lastname: data.data.lastname
                 });
                },
              },
              actions: {
                 init(context) {
                   (new Sqlite("my.db")).then(db => {
                db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people (id INTEGER 
         PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, firstname TEXT, lastname TEXT)").then(id => {
                 context.commit("init", { database: db });
             }, error => {
                 console.log("CREATE TABLE ERROR", error);
               });
             }, error => {
              console.log("OPEN DB ERROR", error);
              });
               },
          insert(context, data) {
            context.state.database.execSQL("INSERT INTO people (firstname, 
lastname) VALUES (?, ?)", [data.firstname, data.lastname]).then(id => {
            context.commit("save", { data: data });
          }, error => {
            console.log("INSERT ERROR", error);
            });
      },
      query(context) {
          context.state.database.all("SELECT firstname, lastname FROM people", []).then(result => {
              context.commit("load", { data: result });
            }, error => {
              console.log("SELECT ERROR", error);
          });
      }
  }
```

});

Vue.prototype.$store = store;

module.exports = store;
store.dispatch("init");

Comment: can you provide how to access the store?

Comment: i have added the location and the store js code to the main ticket, please check

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in the main.ts or main.js file:

```
import store from "./store";
new Vue({
  store,
  render: h => h('frame', [h(App))]),
}).$start();
```

Comment: Main.js already has that code

 import Vue from 'nativescript-vue'
 import App from './components/App'
 import VueDevtools from 'nativescript-vue-devtools'
 import store from './store'

 if(TNS_ENV !== 'production') {
    Vue.use(VueDevtools)
 }



 // Prints Vue logs when --env.production is *NOT* set while building
 Vue.config.silent = (TNS_ENV === 'production')

 Vue.registerElement(
   'RadSideDrawer',
   () => require('nativescript-ui-sidedrawer').RadSideDrawer
 )

 new Vue({
   store,
   render: h => h('frame', [h(App)])
 }).$start();